# Hide Drag Preview - HTML Drag and Drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

I have drag and drop functionality on one of my sites. Once you start dragging one of my dragable divs, there is a transparent preview of the dragged element. This is actually in the way of my users placing the element accurately, as what they are dragging does not directly reflect what is dropped.

Is there a way to remove, or better yet, change the drag preview to a different image?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe you can use the SetDragImage function which is part of the Data Transfer API

The following link has some sample Javascript which attaches an event to the ondragstart event. Using the DataTransfer API you can then set the Drag Image of the event with any Image you want, even an invisible image.

```css
.dragdemo {
    width: 170px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background: green; color: #efe;
}
```

```html
<div id="drag-something" class="dragdemo" draggable="true">drag me</div>
<script>
document.getElementById("drag-something").addEventListener("dragstart", function(e) {
    var crt = this.cloneNode(true);
    crt.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    crt.style.display = "none"; /* or visibility: hidden, or any of the above */
    document.body.appendChild(crt);
    e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(crt, 0, 0);
}, false);
</script>
```

http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/custom-drag-image.html

Hope this helps

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. I knew there had to be some kind of build in functionality for this, just couldnt find it! Thanks!

Comment: Another way to hide the drag image would be something like `event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(new Image(), 0, 0)`

Comment: Not sure why, but the above comment didn't work for me; without a src on the image the drag event didn't fire.  So I set the src to a transparent pixel.

Comment: @benvc is right but you should define the image outside of the react component and set the src to transparent like: `blankImg.src = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAUEBAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=";`
which will give the image time to load to prevent the little gray globe from appearing when dragging