# Angular Material,cdk, Drag & Drop, dropping,and inserting into current position of TextArea Field

Tags: angular, angular-material, textarea, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I was checking these examples:

https://jsfiddle.net/qskxzh0e/3/
http://jsfiddle.net/3p1nra6m/1/
and https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-component-drag

https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview

<strike>It is possible to insert (no replace all contained text) some Token form List as `cdkDropListDropped` or `cdkDrag`?</strike>

I already solved my previous question, because I could insert in the Textarea, and I have new chellenges, Here my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wcxtap?file=src/app/app.component.ts) code (*sorry for the colors and bliking, because I was testing methods*):

For this code, I implemented an interface:

```
export interface EntryKeyValue {
  key: string;
  value: string;
}
```

In my component I have an array like:

```
  ekvs: EntryKeyValue[] = [
    {
      key: 'first',
      value: 'First Item'
    },
    {
      key: 'second',
      value: 'Second Item'
    },
    {
      key: 'third',
      value: 'Third Item'
    },
  ];
```

In my HTML I would like to show the `key` property, but in my Textarea I want to insert the `value` property.

For Example: I should show *'third'*, but I should insert *'Third Item'* in my textarea.

[image]

**How to do it?**

In the `imports` array of my `app.module.ts` file I have commented `//, DragDropModule` because the `*cdkDragPreview` is not shown! In order to the user know what is the final value inserted. But my methods are no working as right bottom square shows!!!

[image]

**Is it compatible `DragDropModule` with my methods?, and how to use both?**

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yhfiqn?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3p1nra6m/1/

Comment: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/9979

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/angular/rnjaakoakda?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchips-drag-drop-example.html

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27990218/1410223 and this post:
https://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/custom-drag-image.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with `textarea` it's better to use [HTML5 Drag and Drop API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API) and that's exactly what you use in your demo.

With Angular CDK drag and drop you will have to detect insertion cursor position in textarea by your own.

If you want to show one value but insert another value you need to pass desired value into [DataTransfer.setData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/setData) method.

Just add some attribute on your dragging element

```
<div 
  class="example-box"
  ...
  [attr.data-drag-data]="ekv.value"
```

Now you can read that value from ts code

```
event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', event.target.dataset.dragData);
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cswaih?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

### Update

In order to customize HTML5 d&d preview you can use [DataTransfet.setDragImage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/setDragImage) method

```
public dragstart_handler(event: any) {
  const preview = event.target.cloneNode(true);
  // store it for element so that we can remove it from DOM later on
  event.target.preview = preview;  
  preview.className = 'preview';
  preview.style.cssText = `position: absolute; top: -100%; left: -100%;
                           width: ${event.target.offsetWidth}px; `;
  document.body.appendChild(preview);
  event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(preview, 0, 0);
...
public dragend_handler(event: any) {
  event.target.preview.parentNode.removeChild(event.target.preview);
```

**[Updated Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mygaxu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: Thanks for your help. But, I have doubt about of how to enable Preview *HTML5 Drag And Drop* replacing the `*cdkDragPreview`?

Comment: @Anita I extended my answer

Comment: `preview`is an arbitrary property when is used in `event.target.preview`? Is not a property according to documentation.

Comment: @Anita Yep, that's just my custom arbitrary property. I use it to store the reference to element that will be acquired by that property and removed from the DOM